# C++ Colored output text when redirected in text file

Tags: command-line, c++

The below code prints "Debug:" in color.

```
printf("\033[1;36mDebug:\033[0m\n");
```

but when I redirect the to a text file the following is written in the out file:

```
<0x1b>[1;36mDebug:[0m<0x1b>
```

What changes in code should be done so that the redirected text should look like plain text.

This should be possible because, when I redirect the colored output of make/g++, plain text is written in the out file.

Comment: You are using this command in a shell? If so, which shell?

Comment: How do you display the contents of the redirected file? A simple `cat your_file` should display the contents ***the same way*** your program displays.

Comment: I am using default Ubuntu 16.04 terminal and to view the out file I am using sublime.

Comment: `<0x1b>` is sublime's way to show you the non-printable escape character that begins the coloring sequences.

Comment: a reference to what @egmont mentioned: [Colour change according to ASCII control characters](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/colour-change-according-to-ascii-control-characters/42797/3)

Comment: "when I redirect the colored output of make/g++, plain text is written in the out file" – g++ autodetects if its output goes to a plain file, and doesn't emit colors by default in that case.

Comment: So how can I do the same i.e. detect redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution:

```
if (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)) // STDERR_FILENO for fprintf(stderr, str);
{
    printf("\033[1;36mDebug:\033[0m\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Debug:\n");
}
```

Using the above code the terminal will show the colored text, but when redirected to a file or pipe, plain text will be used.